# Custom painter Does not change when the listview tile changes

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Currently implementing the custom slider  based on the thermostats in the room, but the problem is when I change the above tile in the listview the custom painter does not repaint the slider with the selected temperature.
Added the  image that will  give the view
[image: Sample Image]

Below is the git repository: https://github.com/sagaracharya24/SampleApp.git

Let me know if any wrong I am doing , I think it is kind of small change but I am not getting it.

Comment: Please check whether my answer works for you.

Comment: It works for me @AdarshM, not sure why the answer is not accepted.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but I cannot reward for at least 13 hours , later then I will do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual issue is `createState()` is not called from `CustomSlider` when you update the values, for that
you have to pass a unique key when creating CustomSlider

```
child: new CustomSlider(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        leftValue: autoCoolingValue,
        rightValue: autoHeatingValue,
      )
```

A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254525/createstate-method-not-always-called-when-creating-new-statefulwidget).

NB: Also, `autoCoolingValue` and `autoHeatingValue` values should be updated within `setState()`, hope you know that drill.