# Flutter circular progress with custom icons

Tags: flutter

[image: 1]
How to create this custom circular bar in flutter

Comment: You can try customPaint

Comment: that will be circled with color like black/gray with shade 100, you can play with opacity

Comment: Check out if this might help you this is the same i did, with minor changes you can make it work as per your needs https://stackoverflow.com/q/63978996/12000053